# Edit arbitrary database values with the SQL Server Management Studio GUI

Tags: ssms

In MySQL Workbench, as long as you can display a row, you can edit it by typing in the cells.

Is there any way to do that with SQL Server Management Studio? SSMS seems limited to providing a GUI editor for the top 200 entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the query used to display the rows to edit by opening the "Query Designer" menu and selecting "Pane"->"SQL".

Once you've made your changes open the "Query Designer" menu and click "Execute SQL".

(Note these commands are also available on the toolbar and have hotkeys associated with them by default).

Comment: To be specific, this only works if you get there by clicking the Edit Top menu item first.

Comment: This... doesn't answer the question at all. No idea why it was marked as the answer.

Comment: @Taz I disagree. The OP indicated that they wanted to extend the the 'Edit Top 200 Rows' functionality, and the answer shows how this can be done.